# Can two project connect each other with MultipeerConnectivity framework?

Tags: ios

I have created two iOS projects.
One used `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` to advertise, and another used `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` to browse. 
My question is that could browser find advertiser?
A device run A project using `MultipeerConnectivity.framework`, if B device want connect with A device, B decides must run A project, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MultipeerConnectivity.framework`, A device and B device must run the same project. You can use `CoreBluetooth.framework`  .